# little problem on complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

[image: how come e^-i*pi*10/3 and e^-i*pi*5/3 can change to ( 0.5 + i *(root3/2)) and (-0.5 + i*(root) 3/2)]

how come e^-i*pi*10/3 and e^-i*pi*5/3 can change to ( 0.5 + i*root3/2) and (-0.5 + i*root 3/2)

Comment: I assume that "j" is the imgainary unit. Please mention it if this is not the case!

Comment: you are right, thank you so much Peter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Use Euler's formula $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$$